# Draw contour around object in Opengl

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics, directx, graphics-programming

I need to draw contour around 2d objects in 3d space. I tried drawing lines around object(+points to fill the gap), but due to line width, some part of it(~50%) was covering object. I tried to use stencil buffer, to eliminate this problem, but I got sth like this(contour is green):

http://goo.gl/OI5uc (sorry I can't post images, due to my reputation)

You can see(where arrow points), that some parts of line are behind object, and some are above. This changes when I move camera, but always there is some part, that is covering it.
Here is code, that I use for drawing object:

```
    glColorMask(1,1,1,1);
    std::list<CObjectOnScene*>::iterator objIter=ptr->objects.begin(),objEnd=ptr->objects.end();
    int countStencilBit=1;
    while(objIter!=objEnd)
    {
        glColorMask(1,1,1,1);
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS,countStencilBit,countStencilBit);
        glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE,GL_KEEP,GL_REPLACE );
        (*objIter)->DrawYourVertices();

        glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL,countStencilBit,countStencilBit);
        glStencilOp(GL_KEEP,GL_KEEP,GL_REPLACE);
        (*objIter)->DrawYourBorder();

        ++objIter;
        ++countStencilBit;
    }
```

I've tried different settings of stencil buffer, but always I was getting sth like that.
Here is question:
**1.Am I setting stencil buffer wrong?**

**2. Are there any other simple ways to create contour on such objects?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

**1.** I don't have normals of objects.

**2.** Object can be concave.

**3.** I can't use shaders(see below why).

Comment: You can check out 'toon' or cell shading, where there is a contour drawn around an object. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/?toon.

Comment: The case is, I can't use shaders in this project...

Comment: @Maciekp Why can't you use shaders? Is this homework?

Comment: This app will have to work on many computers, not always the newest one(that's 1 point).2. It is not a game, this is app with graphics as a part of it+ it will have to work on mac,win,linux.

Comment: It should maybe have been posted on SO if it is not for GameDev and you should give the most information possible if you want your question answered.

Comment: @3nixios it is 3d graphics generation related problem, not programming :)

Answer (score 12):

- Draw your entire scene, except highlighted objects.
- Draw the objects you want to highlight, in pure color, sorted from back to front, and with a small scale applied (1.05f - 1.1f).
- Draw the final objects, again, from back to front.

For extra eye-candy, try drawing the contour pass to a separate render target and apply a small blur, then blend this texture with your final scene using the appropiate Z values.

Comment: This is a great Barba-trick!

Comment: This is the old trick they used for outlines when the gfx pipeline was still fixed.

Comment: That won't work for concave objects

Comment: @Maciekp Your question was about 2D objects (planes) in 3D space, where does concave come into it? Just scale along the two axis != to the face direction.

Comment: It *should* work for concave objects if you invert the normals (you must have face culling enabled) while drawing the contours.

Comment: I think it won't work for concave objects. Imagine object with shape like "V" and it's center in the upper part in the middle. When you scale it, all edges will go further from center. It means - edges inside the shape won't do contour effect. If I am wrong, correct me.

Comment: I know, that if I had normals, I could do this 'simple' way. But I don't have, and I guess, I don't have time to calculate them. @3nixios - concave object, as @zacharmarz said is for example 'V','X','A'etc.

Comment: @Maciekp You could use a simple "text shadowing" type technique where you draw the object multiple times with different offsets; it's really unperformant and the output isn't great but at least it'll work everywhere.

Comment: @3nixios- you mean to draw object ie 5 times, 4 times with offset with solid color, and one the actual object? If so, imagine a circle, and think how would you be supposed to do that

Comment: @Maciekp Yes four times for example , with an offset. This will work on circles and other concave objects, only the end result may not be great.

Comment: Mackiekp is right. Think of a [crescent moon](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/crescent).  When you scale that, the inside of the curve will go the wrong direction.  You'll end up with a nice outline on the outside of the moon, but nothing on the inside.  The ends also won't line up correctly.

Comment: @William I was talking about rendering the object multiple times with different offsets, not scales.

Comment: @Maciekp Sorry, I mean the concave bit earlier.  I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this like that:

- Sort objects in front-back(distance from camera) order
- Draw object's border(as lines and points) with disabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`
- Draw object with enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`
- Do last two steps for every object

I'll try to do this like that, but if anyone have ideas of better solution to this problem(MIND CONCAVE OBJECTS, PLEASE)- feel free to share with us.

PS. I'm not fully satisfied with my solution-changing OpenGL states so often can be harmful. But if no one can help me with stencil buffer settings, I guess that's the only way for me.